# When I try to switch to a new SKScene the scene gets smaller

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to create a game where you have to jump over obstacles. If you hit the obstacle it changes to a different scene with score but that scene is just as wide but not as tall and I don't know why? This is my code:

```
    SKScene *newScene = [[WEnewScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition doorseCloseHorizontalWithDuration:1.0];
    [self.view presentScne:newScene transition:doors];
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. Did you try any other `transition` like `reveal` where `SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];`

Comment: no that didn't seem to work

Comment: Please post more code. Also check the `self.size` height.

Comment: Please post code of the `-initWithSize:` method of the `WEnewScene` class

Comment: and check scene scalemode